# Tomcat home page is not showing when running in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I'm running Tomcat in Eclipse. I would like to see the Tomcat home page, however it doesn't show up. When I browse `http://localhost:8080`, then I get a HTTP 404 Page Not Found error.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Check the process list on your computer - looks like you are running two tomcat instances.

Comment: can you tel me how to check this process

Comment: Nor without knowing more about your setup, no. Are you on Windows/Linux/Mac? What version of the OS, what version of Tomcat, what version of Java?

Comment: I had the same issue and tomcat was returning a status 400. This was due to the fact that my tomcat installation did not have the following directory: tomcat\webapps\ROOT

Inside this directory is the index.html that is being looked for when "http://localhost:8081" is requested.

can you tel me how to solve this problem. that why I am not getting the home page of tomcat

Comment: I Rclick on the project the run on server-->click on ApacheTomcat7...in that way

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Eclipse does by default not use Tomcat standalone. Instead, it overtakes its sole server engine and uses the workspace as deployment space instead of Tomcat's own `/webapps` folder. It also creates copies of configuration files like `server.xml` in the *Servers* project. It untouches the Tomcat installation. It untouches the Tomcat default homepage (and manager). It untouches existing deployments.

As the Tomcat homepage is not one of Eclipse projects (nor would become one), you won't see it when starting Tomcat from inside Eclipse like that. You would only see Eclipse projects which are deployed to the server by *Add/Remove projects*. I'm not sure why you need to see the Tomcat homepage as it has no utter value while developing Java EE web projects. But if you are really dead set on seeing it for some unclear reason, then you'd need to tell Eclipse to not only overtake its engine, but instead use the standalone installation at its entirety.

To configure that, double click Tomcat's entry in *Servers* view to open its configuration and in the *Server Locations* section, choose the option *Use Tomcat installation*.

[image]

You'll now be able to see Tomcat's homepage.

Again, the benefit is highly questionable. Do note that this way Eclipse will modify the Tomcat installation. So the Tomcat installation may not be reuseable across other IDEs/workspaces. You'd need to create a whole new Tomcat installation.

Comment: If use this method, can still use debug mode to run the server code in eclipse line by line?

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse,right click over tomcat server in servier view.
tomcate->properties.click switch location.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps once:

1.Remove schoolManagementsystem folder and war file  from webapps folder

2.Task Manager--> end the all java process

3.Now execute the command `catalina.bat run`   in command prompt.

Hope this will help you .